# How can we download an XML file through ajax in ASP mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

This is my Controller code for returning the XDocument file. I turn it into a MemoryStream then return it as base 64 string.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ImportAcesFileAjax(TransactionViewModel transactionViewModel)
    {
        XDocument xDocument = new XDocument();
        try
        {
            if (transactionViewModel.File.IsNotNullObject())
            {
                ImportService importService = new ImportService();
                xDocument = importService.ProcessExcelFileForTransformation(transactionViewModel);
                _logger.Information($"Finished processing {transactionViewModel.File.FileName}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Error($"Error: {e.Message}");
            _logger.Error(e.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }

        return ReturnImportXmlAsByte(xDocument, "import.xml");
    }
    
    protected ActionResult ReturnImportXmlAsByte(XDocument xDocument, string xmlFilename)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using(XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
        {
            xDocument.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
            var byteLength = stream.ToArray().Length;
            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray(), 0, byteLength);
            return Json(new {base64String = base64String, xmlFilename = xmlFilename});
        }
    }
```

I use the following code in the front end:

```
$.ajax({
    url: requestUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (excelByteResult) {
        var bytes = base64ToBytes(excelByteResult.base64String);
        var blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: "text/xml" });
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.style.display = 'none';
        a.href = url;
        a.download = excelByteResult.xmlFilename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Xhr: " + jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log("Status: " + status);
        console.log("Error Thrown: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

The ajax call is successful but I can't seem to access the file. Are there any alternatives to my approach we may work? The requirement is to download an xml file via ajax

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't seem to access the file"? Is no download dialog shown? Is the file not saved on the client? Are you not able to open the saved file on the client?

Comment: @derpirscher [this](https://i.imgur.com/1rOnfBJ.gif) is the result.

Comment: Well, it says your file is "0 byte". Have you checked in the developer tools, if the response from the server -- especially the base64String) actually contains any data?

Comment: @derpirscher this is correct, I modified the code and the code now works